# Delete skype name from mac

Tags: macos, skype

Ok. So my question is little different. Actually, **I successfully removed all skype names from Skype folder.** But I made an instance of skype (let's called it second instance) using `sudo /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/MacOS/Skype` . And logged in there.

Now my question is though I deleted skype names, I can see the skype names of second instance when I again start it. **So I want to delete those skype names of second instance.**

P.S. - I uninstalled Skype and re-installed it. But still can see the skype names in second instance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the directory in the home of root user:

```
sudo rm -rf ~root/Library/Application\ Support/Skype
```